# Coalesce with BigDecimal in QueryDsl

Tags: querydsl, coalesce

I'm trying to do a Coalesce using QueryDSL without any luck.

Here is what I want to do: I have some `Order` objects which have `OrderItem` objects. Each `OrderItem` has a price (BigDecimal). For each `Order`, I want to have the ID of the `Order` as well as the sum of its `OrderItem` prices, returned in a tuple. My model and my query are actually a bit more complicated than that and for that reason, I have to do the sum in a subquery.

Here is what I wrote:

```
NumberSubQuery<BigDecimal> sumQuery = new HibernateSubQuery()
            .from(qOrderItem)
            .where(qOrderItem.order.eq(qOrder))
            .unique(qOrderItem.price.sum());

HibernateQuery query = new HibernateQuery(session).from(qOrder)
.list(new QOrderTuple(qOrder.id, sumQuery))
```

`OrderTuple` is a tuple that contains only two fields: id (long) and priceSum (BigDecimal).

The query I wrote works properly. Now, I would like to make sure that if the `Order` has no `OrderItem`, then `sumQuery` returns 0 (and not `null`, as it currently does). I thus modified my subquery as follow:

```
    NumberSubQuery<BigDecimal> sumQuery = new HibernateSubQuery()
            .from(qOrderItem)
            .where(qOrderItem.order.eq(qOrder))
            .unique(qOrderItem.price.sum().coalesce(BigDecimal.ZERO));
```

The problem is that this code does not compile since the type returned by `unique()` is now `SimpleSubQuery<BigDecimal>`. However, the constructor of `QOrderTuple` requires a `NumberExpression<? extends BigDecimal>`, not a `SimpleSubQuery<BigDecimal>`.

I also tried to add a `asNumber()` to the `coalesce()`, but I got a `NumberExpression<?>`, which is not accepted by the constructor neither. Eventually, I tried explicit Java casts to make the code compile, but it fails at runtime :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at com.mysema.query.types.ConstructorExpression.newInstance(ConstructorExpression.java:131)
at com.mysema.query.jpa.FactoryExpressionTransformer.transformTuple(FactoryExpressionTransformer.java:50)
at org.hibernate.hql.HolderInstantiator.instantiate(HolderInstantiator.java:96)
at org.hibernate.impl.ScrollableResultsImpl.prepareCurrentRow(ScrollableResultsImpl.java:268)
at org.hibernate.impl.ScrollableResultsImpl.next(ScrollableResultsImpl.java:123)
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong with the coalesce syntax?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How does the runtime failure look like?

Comment: I just added the stacktrace of the runtime error in my post. I investigated a bit more, I got the same error by using `castToNum(BigDecimal.class)` on my subquery. However, I have my example working if I add my subquery to another BigDecimal:
`list(new QOrderTuple(qOrder.id, qOrder.taxAmount.add(sumQuery))`. In that case, providing that Order.taxAmount is a BigDecimal, it is working. But when `sumQuery` is used alone, it does not work.

Comment: We try to avoid the constructions like `x.coalesce(BigDecimal.TEN).add(BigDecimal.ONE)` because it "adds" to coalesce. But it can be easily changed into `ONE.add(x.coalesce(TEN))`. Sometimes you can't switch the order, then we have to use `asNumber()`, cast it to `NumberPath<BigDecimal>` (ugly) and live with it. I thought we can also use `NumberOperation.create(BigDecimal.class, Ops.COALESCE, x, Expressions.constant(TEN)).add(ONE)` - however this expression generates `SELECT (COALESCE(c1amount ) + ?)` (that is 10 is completely missing in COALESCE(...), don't know why).

Comment: Another problem with `NumberOperation.create` for coalesce is, that if you use something like `x.sum()` as an argument, it wil only take x. In any case working with coalesce is not straightforward - and for `BigDecimal` it's also typically unsafe (at least for compler). (BTW: c1amount in previous post should have been x, of course.)